# C# Bound DataGridView to Hashtable

Tags: c#, datatable, hashtable

I want to make a C# DataGridView's `DataSource` be a `HashTable` where there are two columns:

- The first one would be the key;
- The second the value.

Is this possible?

EDIT: Please see my comment about setting/getting the value from/to a hashtable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you cannot bind directly to a `HashTable`. You'll need something that implements: `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList`, `IBindingListView`. HashTable does not implement any of those interfaces.

Try using LINQ to get your `HashTable` into a `List`:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();    
ht.Add(1,"foo");
ht.Add(2,"bar");    
dataGridView1.DataSource = ht.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                             .Select(x => new { Col1 = x.Key.ToString(), 
                                                Col2 = x.Value.ToString() })
                             .ToList();
```

Note that the anonymous class has 2 named properties (I used `Col1` and `Col2` for brevity. Your grid must know about them exactly:

[image]

Comment: Hi! So if I run the code you posted, the existing hashtable will be copied into a compatable type and assigned as the data source? Do I just run this every time I want to update the table with new data from the hashtable? Also, how do I get the data out of the table into the hashtable? THanks!

Comment: @Christian: yes, and yes. You can then use `dgv.Rows` to access the data in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: NO.  DataGridView supports IList, so you could try using a List instead of a Hashtable.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d4745e6e-fcb1-4083-8d4a-e654b5afa75a/